# Time Synchronization Ubuntu Server Under Parallels

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, parallels

I've installed Ubuntu Server (8.04) into Parallels and found that the system time/clock ran fast to the extent that it would gain hours over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [an NTP service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to keep it sync'd?

Comment: Depending on the host O/S, this might be of use: http://kb.parallels.com/en/113271 (assuming the host is keeping correct time?).

Answer (score 0):

You could just want to install ntpd, it works well enough on real servers, should also do the trick on virtual ones. Another possibility is to check if Parallels has a configuration option like "Sync guest clock to host clock".