# Tracking of changed files by Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Do you guys know if it's possible to change the way VS tracks that file has been changed and needs to be recompiled ?

It looks like it's using file's update time rather than tracking what user modified in IDE.

I have my source stored on Linux machine (VmWare) shared via Samba. Pretty often system time on that machine goes off. If time of .cpp files is in the past relative to host system VS never recompiles them :)

Is there way to change this behavior in Visual Studio ?

And of course I manually sync time on VM as well.

Comment: Doing a `Rebuild Solution` will compile the stale files, regardless of their updated time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you're right. That's what I do now. But it's too slow.

Comment: Why not just fix the system time?

Comment: @EdwardThomson, good point. For some reason auto-sync doesn't work properly in Ubuntu 12.04 in VmWare. It never updates time after I suspend-resume VM instance. I suppose Ubuntu syncs it only on system restart which never happens in my case. It's kinda annoying.

Comment: And I thought THAT was weird: http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: It's Linux, why not just fix the operating system?

Comment: @HansPassant, answered in comment above.

Comment: @ruslan I think you can fix your VM by running ntpd. This is a daemon process that periodically checks your system time against the time on a remote NTP server, and adjusts your system time as necessary to keep it in sync with the remove server. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88289/time-synchronization-ubuntu-server-under-parallels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to change this behavior of VS. So I ended up re-configuring `ntpd` on linux machine to update time as often as possible.